# a split-function that accept a string and splits it into value , then sum them up

Tags: javascript

//Write a function ‘SplitFunction’ that accepts the string ‘7+12+100’ and splits it into individual values, then summing these values. (Make use of the split() and parseInt() functions). Return the summed result.
you can see the question above, and my code for this question is:

```
function SplitFunction(str){
let y=str.split('+')
let sum=0
for(i=0;i<y.length;i++){
  sum+=parseInt(y[i])
  return sum  
}
}
console.log(SplitFunction('7+12+100'))
```

But I keep getting results as 7??? and cant find out why

Comment: you're returning too early - try moving that line after the loop.

Comment: u mean moving 'return sum '? just did it and the answer now becomes undefined

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: what do you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move **return sum** beyond **for loop**

```
function SplitFunction(str) {
    let y = str.split('+')
    let sum = 0

    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(y[i]) 
    }

    return sum
}
console.log(SplitFunction('7+12+100'))
```

**Edit**: or you can use this clear code below:

```
var SplitFunction = str => { // taking function called SplitFunction which takes an argument str
    let sum = 0 // set a variable to sum up
    str.split(+).forEach(number => { // split taken problem and for each of them:
        sum += parseInt(number) // cast to Number and add to sum
    })
    return sum // finally return result
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase ok now

Comment: @NicoHaase can you approve my answer, pleeease!!!

Comment: No, I can't do that, that's something solely the person who asked the question can do. Also, `str.split(+)` looks strange to me - shouldn't the first argument be a string or character?

Comment: i think i have approved @Abdulaziz0 's answer ??? im really new to this platform